# Adding data into a middle table from two other tables in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have 3 tables that link with each other: User, Booking and User_Bookings. When the user books a room, I want it so the booking ID and User ID are submitted into the joining table so they can view their bookings and not other peoples. But when the user creates a booking the booking id and user id arent entered into the table, so when they go to view their bookings, they dont see anything as the query doesnt return anything

User_booking Model:

```
class UserBooking < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :users
   belongs_to :bookings
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

   has_secure_password

   validates :email, format: {with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP}, presence: true, uniqueness: true
   has_many :user_bookings
   has_many :bookings, through: :user_bookings
 end
```

Booking Model:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord

  enum room_type: [:Beotuk,:Ugakhpa,:Merinin,:Chahta]

  has_many :user_bookings
  has_many :users, through: :user_bookings
end
```

User_booking schema:

```
 create_table "user_bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "booking_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["booking_id"], name: "index_user_bookings_on_booking_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_user_bookings_on_user_id"
  end
```

Without the data being entered, the website would list all bookings instead of the relevant ones.

my booking_controller create method

```
def create
    @booking = Booking.create(booking_params)
    current_user.bookings << @booking
```

Comment: You need to enter the data in the third table i.e `UserBooking` while creating a `User` or `Book`.

Comment: @RohitLingayat do I need to make a controller for the UserBooking class then? and just pass the objects into it? apart from that is it all valid code?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new booking make sure to add it to the user's bookings collection. Your controller logic should look something like this:

```
@booking = Booking.create(booking_params)
current_user.bookings << @booking
```

This will create the corresponding UserBooking join model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `@booking = current_user.bookings.create(booking_params)` and ActiveRecord will handle creating all the relevant records. Take a look at [the docs for `has_many`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) to see all the conveniences it affords you (and some caveats).